# Visual Studio Project dependencies in svn

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, project-reference

I imported an existing project in our solution. Afterwards I changed the references from an "external dll" to a project reference. (Delete Reference / Add Reference).

I built the project and everything worked. Later that day a co worker updated the solution via svn and tried to build the solution. But he got different errors in the build. The reason was, the new project was build at last. So every Project with a refernce to my new project got an error.

I checked his Project Dependencies and there wasn't any dependencies on the new project. I checked my Project Dependencies and everything was correct.
So my qquestion is, where are the project dependencies saved? The *.sln and the *.proj Files are commited and up to date. In which file I find the project dependencies and how does they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into my .sln file (it's a solution with two projects one depending on the other) and here is a section that I found:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GspService", "GspService\GspService.csproj", "{7D9D9F3A-9405-43E9-900F-A00DF28019A5}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GspTest", "WcfTestApp\GspTest.csproj", "{430F45E5-A6C6-4B0F-8D48-DC99F6D082DA}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {7D9D9F3A-9405-43E9-900F-A00DF28019A5} = {7D9D9F3A-9405-43E9-900F-A00DF28019A5}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

You can see the section

```
ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {7D9D9F3A-9405-43E9-900F-A00DF28019A5} = {7D9D9F3A-9405-43E9-900F-A00DF28019A5}
EndProjectSection
```

references the GspService project, hope this helps